# Flutter nearby connections on IOS

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, core-bluetooth, xpc

I want to make chat app using nearby connections/bluetooth. I was using flutter_nearby_connection pack, which should work on both platform (ios + android), but it works only on IOS emulator. Real device is calling methods flutter -> swift.

I gave a lot of permissions (info.plist / permission handler/NSBonjourServices key). Right now I have a error **[Core Bluetooth] XPC connection invalid** . NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription is added to plist and sandbox is off.

Did someone try this on real IOS? Documentation only has tests on IOS emulator, so idk if its problem by my side. Can u recommend other pack that will allow me to chat between Android - IOS?

MacOs 12.6.2, Xcode 14.2, IOS 15.7.1